# Opening local HTML file with local video and local subtitles

Tags: html, html5-video

When opening a local HTML file in Safari with the following contents

```
<video controls autoplay src="video.mov">
  <track default src="subtitles.vtt" />
</video>
```

where `video.mov` and `subtitles.vtt` are in the same directory as the HTML file, the video is correctly loaded and can be played, but the subtitles are not shown and the following error is logged in the console:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///subtitles.vtt from origin null. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Is it possible to show a local video with local subtitles? Why does the video load correctly but the subtitles do not?

**EDIT**:
I don't intend to install or use a web server for this. I was just wondering why the video loads and the subtitles do not, but using a web server to work around this issue is too cumbersome for my simple needs.

Comment: Did you try to run that using a server? If you're using VS Code you can use [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. Then check if both loaded

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<track>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-track-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.